# Error: Undefined name 'context' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner with flutter, I had just started a few days ago. I want to go from one page to another page . But when I use the navigator it shows an error.

I've tried to solve it using some answers to similar problems on stack overflow, but I can't solve it. Also, I am not able to understand those properly.

These are some of them:

Undefined name 'context'

```
  _buildDrawer() {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: OvalRightBorderClipper(),
      child: Drawer(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 40),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: primary, boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black45)]),
          width: 300,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.power_settings_new,
                        color: active,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 90,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        gradient:
                            LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.pink, Colors.red])),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 40,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profile),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  Text(
                    "Mohd Amin bin Yaakob",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Pegawai",
                    style: TextStyle(color: active, fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                  _buildRow(Icons.home, "Home", () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return HomePageWidgetPage();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                  _buildDivider(),
                  _buildRow(Icons.home, "Home", () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return HomePageWidgetPage();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                  _buildDivider(),
                  _buildRow(Icons.home, "Home", () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return HomePageWidgetPage();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                  _buildDivider(),
                  _buildRow(Icons.home, "Home", () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return HomePageWidgetPage();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                  _buildDivider(),
                  _buildRow(Icons.home, "Home", () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return HomePageWidgetPage();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                  _buildDivider(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Divider _buildDivider() {
    return Divider(
      color: active,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(IconData icon, String title, VoidCallback onTap) {
    final TextStyle tStyle = TextStyle(color: active, fontSize: 16.0);
    return InkWell(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              icon,
              color: active,
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
            Text(
              title,
              style: tStyle,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      onTap: onTap,
    );
  }
}
```

Undefined name 'context' in flutter navigation

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `context` like

```
_buildDrawer(BuildContext context){
```

And the place you call this method

```dart
_buildDrawer(context)
```

Comment: More about [function](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)